# SharePoint 2010 Export to Excel Fails Claims Based Authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, office-integration

We have a 2010 SharePoint implementation and the clients are using Office 2007 SP2 and IE 8.   Security is handled using claims-based authentication over http.   In Office 2010 we are able to go to a list and export to excel.  We get prompted for credentials again but the after that all is good.

Using Excel 2007 on the client results in the following error:

> > You do not have adequate permissions to modify the list.  Changes to your data cannot be saved.

From what I have read this is because Office 2007 doesn't support claims based authentication.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have similar setup ,works fine with https .But not sure if this could be the issue . I faced problem to open a video file in new browser.It asked for username and password.finally i embeded the video files in sharepoint.

Answer (score 2):

Run IE as an Administrator and then try it. It should work or else try the following:

Resolution: (Work-around)
1) Log into the SharePoint site using forms authentication from office 2007 client
2) Open any existing excel document from the site. If you do not have an excel file on the server, upload an excel sheet to any of the document library.
3) It will be opened in browser.
4) Use Open in excel link on the page to open it in excel.
5) open it in read only or edit mode
6) Provide credential on the log- in popup
7) Now go to the SharePoint list and try exporting the list to excel option. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem.

The best way i suggest you to create extended application which will be AD Authenticated.

Below URL will be help you to creating the extended application.

[How to Create or extend Web applications](http://sharepointinstallation.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-to-create-or-extend-web.html)